# Get rid of empty xmlns element in JAX-WS

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I am trying to generate a request like this using JAX-WS Client:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:alin="http://www.alinma.com" xmlns="http://www.alinma.com"> 
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <alin:CustDtlsInqRq>
        <alin:MsgRqHdr>
            <RqUID>BPM11957T201508101626333904816</RqUID>
            <SCId>BPMP</SCId>
            <FuncId>24000000</FuncId>
            <RqMode>0</RqMode>
            <CustLangPref>En</CustLangPref>
            <CustId>
                <CIF>6060</CIF>
            </CustId>
            <AgentId>OprtSupportReviewer</AgentId>
        </alin:MsgRqHdr>
        <Body>
            <CIF>6060</CIF>
        </Body>
    </alin:CustDtlsInqRq>
</soapenv:Body>
```

But the request is generated like this:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://www.alinma.com">
<S:Header/>
<S:Body>
    <ns2:CustDtlsInqRq xmlns:ns2="http://www.alinma.com">
        <MsgRqHdr xmlns="">
            <RqUID>OLPM201508261333149660000020</RqUID>
            <SCId>BPMP</SCId>
            <FuncId>24000000</FuncId>
            <CustLangPref>En</CustLangPref>
            <CustId>
                <CIF>6060</CIF>
            </CustId>
        </MsgRqHdr>
        <Body xmlns="">
            <CIF>6060</CIF>
        </Body>
    </ns2:CustDtlsInqRq>
</S:Body>
```

the added tag `xmlns=""` makes problems in server side
This is the code of my Handler that surround the request with SOAP Envelop

```
if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {

        try {
            SOAPMessage soapMessage = context.getMessage();

            SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
            soapEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("", "http://www.alinma.com");
            // Grab the header of the SOAP envelop
            SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnvelope.getHeader();

            // Attach a new header if there is none...
            if (soapHeader == null) {
                soapHeader = soapEnvelope.addHeader();
            }

            soapMessage.saveChanges();
            soapMessage.writeTo(System.out); //TODO: remove this line (just for debugging)

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error Creating SOAP message", e);
        }  

    }
```

How can I adjust the empty `xmlns` tags?

Comment: Are you using a complex XSD element, if so than you might need to define internal and external namespaces correctly.

Comment: I modified this annotation to the object (MsgRqHdrType) of @XmlType(name = "MsgRqHdr_Type", propOrder = {
    "rqUID",
    "scId",
    "funcId",
    "rqMode",
    "custLangPref",
    "terminalId",
    "terminalDesc",
    "bankId",
    "branchId",
    "networkRefId",
    "custId",
    "usrId",
    "sec",
    "override",
    "agentId",
    "clientDt",
    "echoData",
    "version"
},namespace="http://www.alinma.com")
But this didn't fix the problem

Comment: You need to set targetNamespace element

Comment: refer http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxws/annotations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem.
By mistake I removed the generated file package-info.java which include a header namespace definition for all the package classes

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.alinma.com", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.ejada.sadadolp.bkf.mwservices.core;
```